# ATMega/Tiny barely working on breadboard without ISP

Tags: atmega, noise, attiny, isp

currently I want to get an ATMega328P and an ATTiny85 to work on a breadboard, which should talk to each other and an LCD via TWI.

Anyway, I came across some issues I don't seem to be able to fix at all.
Without an ISP attached the ATTiny doesn't do a thing(programmed it to flash a light for now), connecting the ISP makes it work just fine. Similiar thing with the ATMega, when the ISP is disconnected I can't get correct data over USART. Either it stops transmitting entirely or some garbage is transmitted.

When I started I had a really barebones breadboard wired up, but as suggested in other forums and on here, I added a couple components in the hope to fix it finally.

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: schematic]

Inititally I had a 4.7k as a pull-up on the reset pins, but it was suggested that 10k was better(with AVR circuit design considerations as source). Als the caps for the VCC/GND were added later on to reduce the affects of noise in the power delivery. The caps on the crystal were calculated with the spec sheet of it and a formula found in the ATMega spec sheet.

But nothing really helped. Even when I remove the ATTiny and have the ATMega on it's own, it won't really work.

Also it seems that the voltage on the reset pin is just 20mV. What could be the reason for that?

As a power supply I'm using a board called "ywRobot Power Board" plugged to a adjustable power plug which outputs 12V and can deliver 300mA max.
The crystal is a 20MHz HC-49.

Fuse Bits on the ATMega328P: 0xFF/0xD9/0xEF(Ext/High/Low)(factory default, except clock-source and CKDIV8)

Fuse Bits on the ATTiny85P: 0xFF/0xDF/0x62(Ext/High/Low)(factory default)

Comment: Wong fuse settings? False connection? Bad crystal? Wrong programming? No power? .....

Comment: also happens when using the internal oscilator. I don't really know what to check with the fuse bits. The ATTiny has the factory defaults and the ATMega also has factory defaults except for the clock source and clock divider bit. For the clock-source I have "Ext. Crystal Osc.; Frequency 8.0-    MHz; Start-up time PWRDWN/RESET: 16K CK/14 CK + 4.1 ms; [CKSEL=1111 SUT=10]" selected.

Comment: On the ATTiny the code is just the simple LED blinking, so DDRB4 set and fliping PB4 ever second. The USART code on the ATMega is pretty much just the code from the datasheet with 9600 Baud-rate and two stop-bits. Checked the wiring again, looks like nothing is wrong there.

Comment: 0xEF fuse for ATmega is selecting low power oscillator with frequency range up to 16 MHz if I read CKSEL description in datasheet correctly. I am not sure if it could cause your problems (20 mV on reset pin is really strange regardless clock or anything), but it is not good idea anyway. Use 0xE7 instead (Full Swing Crystal Oscillator).

Comment: ... or, maybe the best, just start testing with default internal RC oscillator, minimizing number of possible problem sources.

Comment: Which programmer are you using? Atmel's AVRISP mk2 should refuse to work when it does not see correct level on RESET pin.

Comment: I'm using a "Diamex-AVR" USB-Dongle.

Comment: Just tested again with the internal at 8MHz and still the same issue.

Comment: I am not able to find much technical info on your programmer, but guessing from the fact it has jumper-selectable voltage -- does it provide voltage at pin #2 of ISP conn? If so, maybe your power supply is faulty in some way and you are powering MCU from programmer instead (which could explain "working only when programmer is connected" thing).

Comment: "reset pin is just 20mV. What could be the reason for that?" - no good reason. You need to find out why it measures so low (could be an open circuit or short in the wiring, bad pull-up resistor, no Vcc...) because without reset pulled up to Vcc the MCUs won't work properly.

Comment: @Martin it indeed does for some reason. I set the dip switches to the positions where it shouldn't supply any voltage, but it does around 2.6V. The ATMega does seem to start working just by connecting VCC and GND of the programmer. ATTiny however only when MISO/MOSI/SCK is connected

Comment: @BruceAbbott just tried with a dedicated pull-up just for the ATMega, 5V is there but still issues.

Comment: Did you discover why 5V wasn't there before installing the dedicated pull-up? You should determine  the cause of _any_ anomaly. Even if it doesn't seem important, It might give you a clue as to what else is wrong.

Comment: @Martin This pin 2 of ISP to which you refer,  where is it?  I do not see any ISP connector.  I see the pins MSIO MOSI SCK are not used.

Comment: @BruceAbbott seems like the ATTiny caused it when it was bugging out/standing still. So the biggest issues was apparently the USB-TTL adapter. I programmed a simple LED blinking program on both ATs and removing the USB-TTL adapter made them both blink as expected. However I've run into another issue. The blinking only correctly works for both as long as I touch the power supply cable. Tried that with a couple different power plugs with the same result. I think I'm screwed unless I get a proper bench-top supply. Or am I?